# How to implement L1 logistic regression?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, data-science, logistic-regression

As part of pursuing a course, I was trying to implement L1 logistic regression using scikit-learn in Python. Unfortunately for the code

```
clf, pred = fit_and_plot_classifier(LogisticRegression(penalty = 'l1', C=1000000))
```

I get the error message

```
ValueError: Solver lbfgs supports only 'l2' or 'none' penalties, got l1 penalty.
```

I tried setting l1_ratio

```
clf, pred = fit_and_plot_classifier(LogisticRegression(l1_ratio = 1))
```

but got the error message

```
C:\Users\HP\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\linear_model\_logistic.py:1499: UserWarning: l1_ratio parameter is only used when penalty is 'elasticnet'. Got (penalty=l2)"(penalty={})".format(self.penalty))
```

So, how to implement L1 Logistic regression?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like you are doing in the first code snippet, but you have to define another solver. Use either ‘liblinear’ or ‘saga’, [check more in the documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.html#sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I think it solved the issue. So, I have to use                                                                                  clf, pred = fit_and_plot_classifier(LogisticRegression(solver='saga', penalty = 'l1', C=1000000)) - if the solver is 'saga' - no?

Comment: For some reason, the above code with penalty, 'l2' also produces the exact same plot.

Comment: I think the reason why the plots are same is due to C being very high. The plots are definitely different for C=1, the default value.